# Build tagging: version increment commit vs. version control labeling

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, version-control, tfvc

As far as I know there are two ways to tag a build:

1. increment AssemblyInfo.cs version and commit the change
2. add a version control label

What are pros and cons of these two approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: What VCS are you using?

Comment: Team Foundation Server, why?

Comment: Because different VCS's handle merges differently. If you have branches and you are committing changes to multiple branches you will potentially have to deal with "spurious" merge conflicts. TFS is the worst for this in my experience so it can have an influence on which strategy to adopt

Comment: Those two approaches are not analogous at all. AssemblyInfo.cs controls the **assembly** version for the compiled application. A version control label has no impact on the build output. Both are appropriate, **in totally different circumstances**. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't agree completely, if I need to fix a problem on build 1.0.232 I can look for the version increment check-in 1.0.232 or a label with the same name. They both give me the option to get that specific version and work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use "Label" since it is more easy to achieve. TFS already supports to label the source code after the build and when you want to get that specific version, you just need to use the label directly. But with assembly version, you need to do more things to increase the version and check in the change. And you need to find the id for that changeset first and then get that version when you want to get it. And also, "label" does not affect the history of source code while "assembly version" will create lots of history if the version increments frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Daniel commented, they are not analogous and Contrary in TFS. It depends which one more suitable for your situation.

`AssemblyInfo.cs` controls the assembly version for the compiled application.

Version control Labels let you take a **snapshot** of your files so that at a later date you can **refer back to that snapshot.** By using your label, you can view, build, or even roll back a large set of files to the state they were in when you applied the label.

More details please refer this link from MSDN: [Use labels to take a snapshot of your files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files)

Comment: As mentioned above, for the specific purpose of getting an older build they should be interchangeable.

Comment: Well, using `AssemblyInfo.cs`  more suitable for daily use. And it's also sutiable for stable version maintenance. However for labels, when your code has reached a reasonable level of quality and stability, the team will build and release a new version of the product. The team needs to mark the *current* version of each file so that even as the files continue to change, the team can still get and build the new version of every file in their project.

Comment: Theoretically, you could record the ID of each changeset for each file manually; but clearly this kind of process is not practical. Team Foundation version control makes the job simple: You apply a label to the folder, branch, or team project that contains the files. You can give the label a name that follows whatever naming convention you prefer. Some examples of label names include: "Sprint 5", "M1", "Beta2", and "Release Candidate 0".

Comment: Seems using label is more suitable for your situation.